# using Zxing library to generate qr code

Tags: android

I am developing an android app, I have an object transaction which has name, email, id, book, isbn. How can I generate a QR code containing my transaction object?

Comment: Please show the code you already tried and describe how it didnt work for you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41606384/how-to-generate-qr-code-using-zxing-library

Comment: You can have a look at this project. It has implemented the same feature
https://github.com/AhmadAyyaz1993/LostAndFound
In this project three libraries are used
         compile 'com.google.zxing:android-core:3.3.0'
         compile 'it.auron:mecard-parser:1.0.9'
         compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.3'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your Object to String using GSON

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(myObj);
```

Then use this method to create the bitmap

```
Bitmap TextToImageEncode(String Value) throws WriterException {
        BitMatrix bitMatrix;
        try {
            bitMatrix = new MultiFormatWriter().encode(
                    Value,
                    BarcodeFormat.DATA_MATRIX.QR_CODE,
                    QRcodeWidth, QRcodeWidth, null
            );

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException Illegalargumentexception) {

            return null;
        }
        int bitMatrixWidth = bitMatrix.getWidth();

        int bitMatrixHeight = bitMatrix.getHeight();

        int[] pixels = new int[bitMatrixWidth * bitMatrixHeight];

        for (int y = 0; y < bitMatrixHeight; y++) {
            int offset = y * bitMatrixWidth;

            for (int x = 0; x < bitMatrixWidth; x++) {

                pixels[offset + x] = bitMatrix.get(x, y) ?
                        getResources().getColor(R.color.QRCodeBlackColor):getResources().getColor(R.color.QRCodeWhiteColor);
            }
        }
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitMatrixWidth, bitMatrixHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);

        bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, 500, 0, 0, bitMatrixWidth, bitMatrixHeight);
        return bitmap;
    }
    }
```